# How would I find the Jacobian matrix for this set of differential equations?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations, jacobian

I am working on a nonlinear dynamics problem set and I am uncertain of how to go about finding the Jacobian matrix for this set of equations. I know that you can use taylor expansion and I should end up with a matrix of partial derivatives... I think I have an answer, I just want to double check! Thank you so much!

Here are the equations:

$\dot{x} = y - x^3 - 3x^2 + I$

$\dot{y} = 1 - 5x^2 - y$

NB: I think that the jacobian is $\begin{bmatrix}3x^2 - 6x & 1\\ -10x & -1\end{bmatrix}$ and it will be evaluated at some point (x*, y*).

Comment: Post your answer and we'll see. BTW, you should say at what point you're linearizing.

Comment: I think that the jacobian is [32−6,1;−10,−1] sorry for the bad matrix notation its a 2x2 with the numbers in appropriate places. And it will be evaluated at some points (x*, y*), (-1,-4) being one of them. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, this is right, assuming $I$ is some constant.

Comment: Ah yay!! Thank you so much. Yes, I is a constant and it can be assumed to be zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Your Jacobian is correct.

$$J = \begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial \dot x}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial \dot x}{\partial y}\\\dfrac{\partial \dot y}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial \dot y}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}3x^2 - 6x & 1\\ -10x & -1\end{bmatrix}$$

**Note:** The comments state that $I$ is a constant and it can be assumed to be zero.

Now, find the critical points and evaluate the eigenvalues of the Jacobian at each of them.

**Update:** I find three critical points

$$(x, y) = (-7.98431, -317.746), (-0.361831, 0.345393), (0.346144, 0.400921)$$

Can you proceed?

Comment: By prime you mean dot, of course. And it's going to be really confusing unless you evaluate at the appropriate point ...

Comment: @TedShifrin: Yes, I mean dot. Good point, I added a note to that affect - a set of steps as you will.

Comment: How exactly do I find the critical points? Do I find the nullclines for each equation and set them equal to each other?

Comment: To find the critical points, simultaneously solve $x' = 0, y' = 0$. Note - you might need to use a numerical solver like Nonlinear Newton's Method to solve them.

Comment: Hmm, I'm confused. Do you know what the equation that determines the x coordinates (x∗) of the fixed points of the model represented by these two ODEs would be?

Comment: For example, from the second equation, you get $y = 1-5x^2$. Substitute that into the first equation and solve for the $x$ values. Clear?